# Why does my Nest thermostat report error e195 when I try to use the air conditioning?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I had a [Nest E](https://nest.com/thermostats/nest-thermostat-e/overview/) installed in February and it has worked really well until it was time to turn on the AC. Now I get random e195 errors (no power detected to the R wire).

The most likely answer from my research is that I need a c wire installed. A friend of mine who's an electrician installed one from the furnace to the Nest. But we are left wondering where to connect the c wire on the furnace. We tried in the "B" terminal but that didn't work.

Would anyone be able to help from the schematics attached?

[image: Furnace Diagram] [image: Hi Velocity Control Panel]

Comment: Note in the top right “designates 24v common terminal” and there appears to be 2 choices at the bottom of the diagram.

Comment: @Tyson Agreed, but one goes to the AC unit and the other one goes to the Hot Water Valve. Not sure that would do anything for the thermostat? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @isherwood It's the same as a "regular" Nest, just $100 cheaper or so. I got it for free through a government program.

Comment: I just noticed a third in the center.  And yes they are all electrically “24v common”

Comment: @Tyson Let me try that tonight and see if that works. Thanks for your help!